# Cross Platform NPAPI Interfacing/Integrating

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform, embedding, npapi

I would like to use Google Earth in one of my cross platform C++ applications, and the only way I can see that would allow me to integrate it nicely into my GUI and interface to it using it's [Javascript API](http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/reference/index.html) would be using it as an NPAPI plugin. Are there any libraries that make interfacing/integrating with these plugins easy, or any tutorials that describe the process?

Comment: So you want to be a NPAPI host in other words?

Comment: Yes, however I want to stress that the UI is not based on any kind of HTML, I want to draw what they would usually draw in a browser screen on a rectangle I define in my UI.

Comment: I don't believe there are any such libraries; I work with NPAPI plugins extensively. FireBreath has a NPAPIHost project that was created to start down that path but it hasn't been worked on in quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

You could embed gecko (mozilla) in order to display any Internet plugin :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Embedding_Basics

It s cross platform, though it's not always easy to embed depending what UI library you are using (I had some problems with Qt 3.3 and macosx in the past...).

You could also implement it ( I have done it in the past), it s around 2-3k c code line. It s not easy because lot of the stuff is not well documented and very platform dependant. Also it's evolving all the time (Gecko source is a good start for that).